# Cypress ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: javascript, babeljs, browserify, e2e-testing, cypress

I updated Cypress from `3.0.3` to `3.1.3`. Im using ES6 import/export modules which must be working related to docs. But Im getting a line with `undefined` in terminal and following error in the GUI:

```
<root_dir>/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/defineProperty.js:1
export default function _defineProperty(obj, key, value) {
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

My tests are in vanilla JS, no TS os CoffeeScript. Im stuck, in `3.0.3` it worked fine.

Comment: This is the only question I can find specific to resolving this error in a Cypress framework.

Comment: [This example](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-typescript-example) helped me to have Cypress and typescript work. The exemple includes how to integrate with Cucumber, but it should be useable without cucumber with few changes.

Answer (score 20):

This error is caused by the presence of modern keywords like "import" and "export" when Cypress runs in the browser.  Unlike Selenium or Protractor -- it actually runs inside the browser.   Since browsers don't support modern JS yet, you'll need to use webpack or browserify to transpile your code.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/preprocessors-api.html#Examples

Here is a fantastic blog post on how to get Cypress to work with modern JS and Typescript using webpack:
https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/use-typescript-with-cypress/

^^ The post is focused on TypeScript, but the configuration options for Javascript will be similar.

The following npm packages must be installed and in your package.json:

```
"@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^4.1.0",
"cypress": "^3.3.1",
"ts-loader": "^6.0.3",
"typescript": "^3.5.2",
"webpack": "^4.34.0"
```

Webpack should be installed using:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack typescript ts-loader
npm install --save-dev @cypress/webpack-preprocessor
```

The following should be present under the "compilerOptions" section of a file called tsconfig.json in your root directory, with "allowJs" set to true for non-typescript users:

```
"module": "es6",
"target": "es6",
"types": ["cypress"],
"allowJs": true
```

A file called "webpack.config.js" should be present in your root directory with the following:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
}
```

And these exports should be present under cypress/plugins/index.js:

```
const webpack = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor')
module.exports = on => {
  const options = {
    // send in the options from your webpack.config.js, so it works the same
    // as your app's code
    webpackOptions: require('../../webpack.config'),
    watchOptions: {}
  }

  on('file:preprocessor', webpack(options))
}
```

Note this final bit at the end of the Cypress plugins file,

```
on('file:preprocessor', webpack(options))
```

That is where Cypress is told to process your modern JS code in such a way as to make it Cypress-runnable.

Comment: Thank, @emery! This fixed everything for me!

Comment: I tried it, and now I'm getting a different error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in ...` :-(

Comment: I found the cause for my error: I had `import "cypress"` at the beginning of the file (because previously WebStorm marked `describe` as unknown name). After removing this line it worked!

Comment: I've tried following this but I already have a quite robust webpack config file. I was able to get the cypress "home" screen, and my React app, to load when I insert this webpack config code in before the final "file loader" but I'm still unable to get the tests to run. Lots of various webpack errors, although I do get a bunch of Typescript errors coming out, although the fact that my file is not seeing my installed cypress types is a whole separate problem (https://stackoverflow.com/q/58982852/6826164)

Comment: ES modules and the `import` keyword has been supported since Chrome 61 @emery 

Comment: I tried the above solution and does not work for me. Can you look at this [question](https://github.com/Shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/issues/49)

Comment: Did you try this package? https://github.com/bahmutov/add-typescript-to-cypress it was recommended by the blog post here https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/use-typescript-with-cypress/ -- this blog post might actually be a better alternative to the answers here if you are having trouble with the above.

Answer (score 9):

I solved it, in my root folder was a `babel.config.js` file which possibly overrode Cypress configs. After I deleted it, everything is working. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

**Update:**
Maybe the magic was readd the `babel.config.js` with this content based on this issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2945

```
module.exports = process.env.CYPRESS_ENV
  ? {}
  : { presets: ['@vue/babel-preset-app'] }
```

Comment: could you please share your cypress config setup so that we can benefit from your solution?

Comment: Hi @emery
yep, my cypress config is based on [official docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Options), nothing special stuff were added. I updated my answer with contents of my new **babel.config.js**.

Comment: CYPRESS_ENV has  renamed to CYPRESS_INTERNAL_ENV

Answer (score 6):

In case people are coming here for the message...

> ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

... in a Cypress TypeScript project. Here is the answer:

Cypress does support TypeScript out of the box, as long as you have a `tsconfig.json` file. However, **imports** don't work unless you preprocess your TypeScript files.

Here are the steps:

1. Install webpack: `yarn add -D webpack`
2. Install ts-loader: `yarn add -D ts-loader`
3. Install @cypress/webpack-preprocessor: `yarn add -D @cypress/webpack-preprocessor`

Now, make sure you have these 3 files,`tsconfig.json`, `webpack.config.js` and `plugins/index.js` on your Cypress folder.

[image]

`plugins/index.js`:

```
const wp = require("@cypress/webpack-preprocessor");

module.exports = on => {
    const options = {
        webpackOptions: require("../webpack.config.js")
    };
    on("file:preprocessor", wp(options));
};
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress"]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            // skip typechecking for speed
                            transpileOnly: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It should just work now.

Comment: After spending hours "transpileOnly: true" worked!
Thanks :)

Comment: I tried the above one and does not works for me. Could you look at this [question](https://github.com/Shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/issues/49)

Answer (score 2):

When using @vue/cli you can simply do (which is commented in Cypress `/plugins/index.js`):

```
const webpack = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('file:preprocessor', webpack({
        webpackOptions: require('@vue/cli-service/webpack.config'),
        watchOptions: {},
    }));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an official sample on github available at this address https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/preprocessors__typescript-webpack

Note: if you are on **windows** and want to **run localy the project**, first update the path in the package.json.

```
// D:\path\cypress-example-recipes\examples\preprocessors__typescript-webpack\package.json

{
  "name": "cypress-example-typescript-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Example showing TypeScript tests with Cypress",
  "scripts": {
    // ...
    "cypress:open": "..\\..\\node_modules\\.bin\\cypress open"
  }
}
```