# How to add test case grouping in Cypress

Tags: testng, grouping, cypress, testcase, ui-testing

I am currently working on UI Integration tests using Cypress. I am looking for ways to add test case grouping in cypress similar to the standard TestNG. I was not able to find any grouping features in cypress documentation. I did find this post: [link](https://www.mariedrake.com/post/using-tags-to-filter-your-cypress-tests) where grouping is done using tags. I am looking for a simpler way for test case grouping.

Here is my use case: I have tests for different features like feature1,2,3 in below example and each feature has different test cases. I would like to run my tests for individual features like Feature 1. Is there a way to run test1 of Feature 1. **Note: I am not looking for .only or .skip**. I would like to add grouping and run these tests using CLI for a particular group.
Has anyone worked on these before?

```
describe('Feature1', () => {
    it('test1', () => {
    })

    it('test2', () => {
    })

    it('test3', () => {
    })

})

describe('Feature2', () => {
    it('test1', () => {
    })

    it('test2', () => {
    })

    it('test3', () => {
    })
})


describe('Feature3', () => {
    it('test1', () => {
    })

    it('test2', () => {
    })

    it('test3', () => {
    })
})
```

Thanks,
Saahith

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can dynamically `skip` a test by using `this.skip()`, which can be applied conditionally based on, say, an environment variable.

To do it globally add a `beforeEach()` in **cypress/support/index.js**.

```js
beforeEach(function() {

  const testFilter = Cypress.env('TEST_FILTER');
  if (!testFilter) {
    return;
  }
  
  const testName = Cypress.mocha.getRunner().test.fullTitle();
  if (!testName.includes(testFilter)) {
    this.skip();
  }
})
```

Note, you must use a `function()` not an arrow function.

The variable `testName` includes the text from nested `context()`, `describe()`, and `it()`, for example, in the sample **assertions.spec.js** provided by Cypress

This

```js
context('Assertions', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io/commands/assertions')
  })

  describe('Implicit Assertions', () => {
    it('.should() - make an assertion about the current subject', () => {
```

has a `testName` of

```
"Assertions Implicit Assertions .should() - make an assertion about the current subject"
```

**In package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "cy:open": "cypress open",
    "cy:filter:implicit": "set CYPRESS_TEST_FILTER=Implicit & cypress open"
  },
```

Note the **CYPRESS_** prefix, but in the code it's just **TEST_FILTER**.

Then,

```
yarn cy:filter:implicit
```

will skip all the "Explicit Assertions" tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked. I have passed the test group variable from cli and used the code given in global support/index.js file to skip the test for the particular group.

Comment: Thank for this comment, is this possible to use in index.ts file.. it is showing below error 
"Property 'mocha' does not exist on type 'Cypress & CyEventEmitter'.
how to resolve in ts file

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the [Cypress-Select-Tests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-select-tests) plugin.

1.Install the plugin using npm `install --save-dev cypress-select-tests`

2.Once installed, write under `cypress/plugins/index.js`:

```
const selectTestsWithGrep = require('cypress-select-tests/grep')
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', selectTestsWithGrep(config))
}
```

Now based on your requirement you can execute your tests like:

```
 ## run tests with "works" in their full titles 
 $ npx cypress open --env grep=works

 ## runs only specs with "foo" in their filename 
 $ npx cypress run --env fgrep=foo

 ## runs only tests with "works" from specs with "foo" 
 $ npx cypress run --env fgrep=foo,grep=works

 ## runs tests with "feature A" in the title 
 $ npx cypress run --env grep='feature A'

 ## runs only specs NOT with "foo" in their filename 
 $ npx cypress run --env fgrep=foo,invert=true

 ## runs tests NOT with "feature A" in the title 
 $ npx cypress run --env grep='feature A',invert=true
```

Now in case you want to write your own custom logic to filter out tests, you can do that as well. In your `cypress/plugins/index.js` use this module as a file preprocessor and write your own `pickTests` function.

```
const selectTests = require('cypress-select-tests')

// return test names you want to run
const pickTests = (filename, foundTests, cypressConfig) => {

  // found tests will be names of the tests found in "filename" spec
  // it is a list of names, each name an Array of strings
  // ['suite 1', 'suite 2', ..., 'test name']

  // return [] to skip ALL tests
  // OR
  // let's only run tests with "does" in the title

  return foundTests.filter(fullTestName => fullTestName.join(' ').includes('does'))
}

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', selectTests(config, pickTests))
}
```

You can refer to these examples as well for further reference: [cypress-select-tests-example](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-select-tests-example) and [cypress-examples-recipes grep](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/preprocessors__grep).

Comment: I tried this but I encountered the following exception...SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (17:0).

Comment: You can look into this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56693706/4571271 to resolve the exception.

Comment: Faced the following issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65047851/cypress-throwing-syntaxerror-import-and-export-may-appear-only-with-source when tried something like above.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you @Alapan.