# Cypress - Running only specific test cases from the test suite

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have 5 test cases in single suite file (TestCase1, TestCase2, TestCase3, TestCase4 and TestCase5) within integrations folder.

**My Requirement**: I need to run only TestCase2 and TestCase5.

Command to run a single test case from the command line:

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --spec 'cypress/integration/TestCase2.js
```

**Query**: How can I run TestCase2 and TestCase5 together using `--spec` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, you say **5 test cases in single suite file** but your example `cypress run --spec 'cypress/integration/TestCase2.js` implies individual spec files.

I'll give you an answer both ways.

---

**Individual spec files**

Please see the third example [docs - cypress run --spec](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run-spec-lt-spec-gt)  which runs two tests, comma separated.

```
cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/TestCase2.spec.js,cypress/integration/TestCase5.spec.js"
```

---

**Single suite file**

Please see [How to add test case grouping in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65045605/14783414) which uses a `beforeEach()` to check test names passed in by ENV variable.

Add this at the top of your single test suite

```js
beforeEach(function() {

  const testFilter = Cypress.env('TEST_FILTER');
  if (!testFilter) return;                       // exit if no filter defined

  const testName = Cypress.mocha.getRunner().test.fullTitle();
  if (!testFilter.includes(testName)) {
    this.skip();
  }
})
```

Run with

```
set CYPRESS_TEST_FILTER=Test2;Test5 & cypress open
```

or

```
cypress open --env TEST_FILTER=Test2;Test5
```

**Note** when using the `--env` flag, the test names must not be separated by a comma since Cypress uses that internally to delimit multiple ENV variables.

Comment: I was pointing to "Individual spec files" and the solution given by you worked. 

Thank you for the answer. It helped.

Comment: user14783414 
if i want to run a specific set of specs then how to run them 
For example if i have total of 50 specs to test containing 10 iterations each 
Now I want to run only 25 among them 
so is there any way to do that like if I have a text file and that text file can have paths of all files to test and cypress uses CLI command to get specs from that file or dictionary and run rather than manually setting specs with comma separation?