# Stop a test if assertion failed

Tags: cypress

I have a simple Cypress test:

```js
    describe('My First Test', () => {
      it('Go to login page', () => {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
        cy.contains('Log in').click()
      })

      it('Login with local account', () => {
        cy.get('input[type=email]').type('123@123.com')
        cy.get('input[type=password]').type('asd123')
        cy.contains('Log in').type('{enter}')
      })
    })
```

The first assertion checks if there's a element with the text `Log in`, then clicks it. Second assertion tries to log in.

I've changed the text in the `Log in` button to `Assertion Failed`. So now the first assertion fails, but it still runs the second assertion even though I'm not redirected to the login page.

Is there a way to cancel a running spec when a assertion fails?

Comment: these are 2 different tests. It is just an alias of test,if you want it to fail, merge them into one test source: https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout

Comment: The above comment is the correct answer. The describe construct groups together tests. But each test should stand alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an `afterEach()` and write this:

```
afterEach(function() {
  if (this.currentTest.state === 'failed') {
    Cypress.runner.stop()
  }
});
```

Or

You can use the plugin [cypress-fail-fast](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-fail-fast) and configure it at the Test level:

```
describe("All tests", {
  failFast: {
    enabled: false, // Children tests and describes will inherit this configuration
  },
}, () => {
  it("sanity test", {
    failFast: {
      enabled: true, // Overwrite configuration defined in parents
    },
  }, () => {
    // Will skip the rest of tests if this one fails
    expect(true).to.be.true;
  });

  it("second test",() => {
    // Will continue executing tests if this one fails
    expect(true).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

or, globally for all specsby writing in `cypress.json`:

```
{
  "env":
  {
    "FAIL_FAST_ENABLED": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```js
afterEach(() => {
  if (cy.state('test').state === 'failed') {
    Cypress.runner.stop()
  }
})
```

but there is a problem with this, none of your `after()` hooks will run, including plugins like code-coverage.

A better solution is to dynamically skip following tests, similar to this answer [How to add test case grouping in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65045605/15544695)

```js
beforeEach(function() {
  const suite = cy.state('test').parent
  if (suite.tests.some(test => test.state === 'failed')) {
    this.skip()
  }
})
```

This is my simplified test

```js
describe('all tests', () => {

  describe('fail fast', () => {

    beforeEach(function() {               // move up to apply to all tests
      const suite = cy.state('test').parent;
      if (suite.tests.some(test => test.state === 'failed')) {
        console.log(`skipping test "${cy.state('test').title}"`)
        this.skip()
      }
    })

    after(() => {
      console.log('after')               // runs
    })

    it('fails', () => {
      expect(true).to.eq(false)          // fails
    })

    it('next', () => {
      expect(true).to.eq(true)           // skipped
    })
  })

  describe('no fail fast', () => {
    it('no skip', () => {
      expect(true).to.eq(true)           // runs
    })
  })
})
```