# Cypress retries making test always pass

Tags: continuous-integration, cypress

I am attempting to use the Cypress (at 7.6.0) retries feature as per https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries#How-It-Works

but for some reason it seems to be not working, in that a test that is guaranteed to always fail:

```
describe('Deliberate fail', function() {
    it('Make an assertion that will fail', function() {
        expect(true).to.be.false;
    });
});
```

When run from the command line with the config retries set to 1,

```
npx cypress run --config retries=1 --env server_url=http://localhost:3011 -s cypress/integration/tmp/deliberate_fail.js
```

it seems to pass, with the only hint that something is being retried being the text "Attempt 1 of 2" and the fact that a screenshot has been made:

[image]

The stats on the run look also to be illogical:
1 test
0 passing
0 failing
1 skipped (but does not appear as skipped in summary)

Exactly the same behavior when putting the "retries" option in cypress.json, whether as a single number or options for runMode or openMode.

And in "open" mode, the test does not retry but just fails.

I am guessing that I'm doing something face-palmingly wrong, but what?

Comment: It's working (that is failing) for me.

Comment: @sarah what does the output give in your case?

Comment: All the trappings of a failed test - red text, "failed: 1", "(Attempt 1 of 2)" (but not 2 of 2), summary = "1 of 1 failed (100%)". I tried the retries config every way - command line, cypress.json, test parameter. Also run mode and open mode.

Comment: I have bumped into this problem, for example, I say `cy.get("whatsupppp").should("be.visible");` and this fails the first attempt on timeout, then proceeding to the second attempt it just logs `waiting to retry..` and proceeds quickly to the next tests whereas I expected it to fail. Second attempt isn't even running properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause .. to fix the problem that Cypress does not abort a spec file when one of the test steps (the it() steps) fails, I had the workaround for this very old issue https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/518 implemented

```
//
// Prevent it just running on if a step fails
// https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/518
//

afterEach(function() {
    if (this.currentTest.state === 'failed') {
        Cypress.runner.stop()
    }
});
```

This means that a describe() will stop on fail, but does not play well with the retry apparently.

My real wished-for use case is to retry at the describe() level, but that may ne expensive as the above issue just got resolved but the solution is only available to those on the Business plan at $300/mo. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/518#issuecomment-809514077

Comment: Please see [Stop a test if assertion failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67133707/9622173) for a better way to stop the runner (no charge for that).

Comment: @Sarah good tip and an improvement to status quo, but unfortunately this technique also makes the spec appear to pass when retries are enabled, as the retry gets skipped. Disabling the stop-on-fail when retrying with if (Cypress.config('retries').runMode === 0) helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are not testing anything. Cypress will retry operations that involve the DOM, because the DOM takes time to render. Retrying is more efficient than a straight wait, because it might happen quicker.

So I reckon because you are just comparing 2 literal values, `true` and `false`, Cypress says, "Hey, there is nothing to retry here, these two values are never going to change, I'm outta here!"

I was going to say, if you set up a similar test with a DOM element, it might behave as you are expecting, but in fact it will also stop after the first attempt, because when it finds the DOM element, it will stop retrying. The purpose of the retry is to allow the element to be instantiated rather than retrying because the value might be different.

I will admit that I could be wrong in this, but I have definitely convinced myself - what do you think?

Comment: The same thing happens if I try a simple DOM-based failing assertion like cy.get('#id-not-exist'). I had just reduced the test case down to eliminate possible causes. But I think you are thinking about the way Cypress retries assertions during a test. What I'm doing here is using the config option to retry the actual test.