# Cypress e2e testing of a project, Enable or disable a it block dependent on condition

Tags: testing, cypress, e2e

Suppose I have the following spec containing 2 **it** blocks, one checks the menu items for teacher role, and another one checks for student role. The variable **rolesToCheck** contains the roles on which basis **it** block will be activated, Currently, the **rolesToCheck** variable only contains the student hence it will run only the second **it** block. Is it possible to do so?

```
   describe('side menu check', () => {
    var sideMenuHelper;
    var rolesToCheck = ['student'];
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.login();
        cy.wait(5000);
    });

    it('menu item check for teacher', () => {
        .....
    })

    it('menu item check for student', () => {
        .....
    })

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see this question [How to add test case grouping in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65045102/how-to-add-test-case-grouping-in-cypress/65045605#65045605) which can be adapted to use the rolesToCheck array.

```js
const rolesToCheck = ['student'];

beforeEach(function() {

  const testName = Cypress.mocha.getRunner().test.fullTitle();
  if (!rolesToCheck.some(role => testName.includes(role))) {
    this.skip();
  }
})

it('menu item check for teacher', () => {        // skipped
    .....
})

it('menu item check for student', () => {        // run
    .....
})
```

---

You may find it is a little difficult to filter by test name when there's a lot of tests, so instead you could use tags

```js
const rolesToCheck = ['student'];

beforeEach(function() {

  const tag = Cypress.mocha.getRunner().test._testConfig?.tag;
  
  if (!tag) return;    // no tag, run it 

  if (!rolesToCheck.includes(tag)) {
    this.skip();
  }
})

it('menu item check for teacher', { tag: 'teacher' }, () => {     // skipped
    .....
})

it('menu item check for student', { tag: 'student' }, () => {     // run
    .....
})
```

Note the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `_testConfig?.tag` in case there's no tag defined on the test.

Comment: Inside the beforEach block this.skip() throws an error showing this.skip is not a function. Can you tell me the reason behind it?

Comment: I think you have used an arrow function `beforeEach(() => {`, but above I have `beforeEach(function() {`. The Mocha library (which Cypress uses) recommends not to use arrow functions, preferring "normal" functions so that `this` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the `rolesToCheck` array and run your tests based on roles in your array.

```
describe('side menu check', () => {
    var sideMenuHelper;
    var rolesToCheck = ['student'];
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.login();
        cy.wait(5000);
    });

    rolesToCheck.forEach(role => {
        it(`menu item check for ${role}`, () => {
            .....
        })
    })    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the **rolesToCheck** array and login based on the role to check the menu items for that role instead of using different ***it*** block for different role.

You can do something like this.

```
const rolesToCheck = ['teacher', 'student'];
rolesToCheck.forEach((role) => {
    describe('side menu check', () => {
        before(() => {
            if (role === 'teacher') {
                login as teacher
            } else if(role === 'student') {
                login as student
            }
        });

        it(`menu items check for ${role}`, () => {

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe the user and roles are orthogonal, i.e many roles assigned to one user.